# Network Error on Chrome when downloading large files

Tags: javascript, axios, download, chromium, large-files

We are downloading files using Axios from AWS S3 storage, but when the files are large, there seems to be a limit on Chrome where the request fails (but server returns 200 OK). We tried it on Firefox and we can download multiple large files at once without an issue.

The situation:

1. We have 4 large video files (about 12 GB each)
2. User triggers a download of one of these files and the downloading starts just fine (downloading is via Axios, not a browser)
3. While the download is running (can be immediately after the start of the first download), the user triggers a download of a second file. But this request immediately fails even though the server returns 200 OK, but in the dev tools network tab you can see that the request failed and Axios throws "Network error" without any further info.

- This limit seems to be device dependent as my colleague is able to trigger 3 downloads of the same files before it fails. But it is consistent.
- The issue is the same on MS Edge browser (chromium based), but not on Firefox.
- Downloading many smaller (tens or hundreds of MB) number of files does not throw this error. But I'm guessing if we had enough simultaneous downloads running the issue would appear as it seems to be connected to overall size of concurrent downloads.
- I'm using the latest version of said browsers

Does Chrome have some kind of limit on downloading large files? If so, how can we bypass/workaround this limit?

I have tried searching for this issue, but I didn't find anything that would match our case.

Comment: It sounds to me it's maybe either a webserver configuration you need to add, or Chromium based browser's manage downloads in a way that collides with your webserver thus terminating the connection and you need to look for a workaround for that. Hope this helps in your research.

Comment: I tried using our application to download a file from a different server (https://speed.hetzner.de/) and it has the same issue, so it does not seem like a webserver configuration. Especially if the webserver is S3 from Amazon.

Comment: Then as I mentioned before this is a Chrome issue. Doing a search, I found complaints about the same problem from years ago but, cannot find any workarounds apart from using a download manager or switching to Firefox.

Comment: Could you send me the links that you found, please?

Comment: [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=334392)`Chromium Forum`
[link](https://superuser.com/questions/1704792/how-to-download-very-large-files-in-chrome) `question`